# How to create a PK by summing a column value and a self-increasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm working on an ETL and I need to create a new table. This table has no PK in the source so I must create it in my Staging.

This is the query from where I extract the data:

```sql
SELECT PP.PRVECODI,
       VW.GRUPDESC,
       VW.FAMIDESC,
       PP.ARTICODI,
       VW.ARTIDESC,
       PP.PROVREFER,
       PP.PPLNMARCA,
       PP.PPLNORIGEN,
       ( SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM   CPR05.ACUERDOSCOMPRA AC
         WHERE AC.ARTICODI = VW.ARTICODI
         AND   AC.ACUCDESDE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND   AC.ACUCHASTA >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND AC.PRVECODI = PP.PRVECODI ) ACUERDOS,VW.SBFMDESC
FROM   CPR05.SAC_VWARTICULOS VW
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                ARTICODI,
                PL.PROVREFER,
                PL.PPLNMARCA,
                PL.PPLNORIGEN,
                P.PRVECODI
         FROM   CPR05.PROPUESTASLINEAS PL 
                INNER JOIN CPR05.PROPUESTAS P
                ON (P.PPTACODI = PL.PPTACODI)
                   AND P.PPTAFECFIN >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       ) PP
       ON (VW.ARTICODI=PP.ARTICODI)
ORDER BY
       VW.GRUPDESC,
       VW.FAMIDESC,
       VW.ARTIDESC
```

I need to create a Table to insert this query and the PK must be a combination between the PP.ARTICODI column and a self-increasing integer.

I have tryed to combine the identity column with the ARTICODI but its not working:

```
CREATE TABLE CENTRALCOMPRASSTG..ProveedoresCatalogo(
  IDProveedoresCatalogo INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  PRVECODI NUMERIC(9,0),
  GRUPDESC NVARCHAR(40),
  FAMIDESC NVARCHAR(40),
  ARTICODI NUMERIC(9,0),
  PROVREFER NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNMARCA NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNORIGEN NVARCHAR(50),
  ACUERDOS INT,
  SBFMDESC NVARCHAR(40)
)
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ue1.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are asking how to have an `IDENTITY` column that is partitioned by or based off another column (so you could have two `1` values for different `ARTICODI` values) then you cannot as that is not supported. If you are asking something else then your question is unclear and you should [edit] it to give an [MRE] showing your expected input and outcome.

Comment: primary keys can be composed from more than one column, possible if this is what you mean

Comment: @nikos-m in this case I dont need a constraint pk but a combination of and auto incremental integer and a current column, please check Expected output

Comment: @MT0 Sorry, edited

Comment: Is your code really meant to use on an Oracle database? The way it uses IDENTITY and in-line the PRIMARY KEY constraints makes it look like SQL Server (although you've tagged your post as Oracle)

Comment: @vstrien sorry im new to the forum. I meant the source is ORACLE but the destination table is SQL-Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle 12c and later, you can use an `IDENTITY` column to generate the unique value and then a virtual column to combine it with the `ARTICODI` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ProveedoresCatalogo (
  IDProveedoresCatalogo INT
                        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(
                                              START WITH   1000000
                                              INCREMENT BY 1000000
                                            )
                        PRIMARY KEY
                        NOT NULL,
  ExpectedPK            INT
                        GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( IDProveedoresCatalogo + ARTICODI )
                        UNIQUE,
  ARTICODI              NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL, -- Ensure this is only 6 digits
  PRVECODI              NUMBER(9,0),
  GRUPDESC              NVARCHAR2(40),
  FAMIDESC              NVARCHAR2(40),
  PROVREFER             NVARCHAR2(20),
  PPLNMARCA             NVARCHAR2(20),
  PPLNORIGEN            NVARCHAR2(50),
  ACUERDOS              INT,
  SBFMDESC              NVARCHAR2(40)
)
```

Then, if you:

```sql
INSERT INTO ProveedoresCatalogo ( ARTICODI, PRVECODI )
SELECT 700002, 13757 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 700002, 10561 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 700002, 51212 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT IDProveedoresCatalogo,
       ExpectedPK,
       ARTICODI,
       PRVECODI
FROM   ProveedoresCatalogo
```

Outputs:

> ```
> IDPROVEEDORESCATALOGO | EXPECTEDPK | ARTICODI | PRVECODI
> --------------------: | ---------: | -------: | -------:
>               1000000 |    1700002 |   700002 |    13757
>               2000000 |    2700002 |   700002 |    10561
>               3000000 |    3700002 |   700002 |    51212
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c33392c4e123c409ce630c8340f12ea)*

---

In SQL Server:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ProveedoresCatalogo (
  IDProveedoresCatalogo INT
                        IDENTITY( 1000000, 1000000 )
                        PRIMARY KEY
                        NOT NULL,
  ExpectedPK            AS ( IDProveedoresCatalogo + ARTICODI )
                        UNIQUE,
  ARTICODI              NUMERIC(6,0) NOT NULL, -- Ensure this is only 6 digits
  PRVECODI              NUMERIC(9,0),
  GRUPDESC              NVARCHAR(40),
  FAMIDESC              NVARCHAR(40),
  PROVREFER             NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNMARCA             NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNORIGEN            NVARCHAR(50),
  ACUERDOS              INT,
  SBFMDESC              NVARCHAR(40)
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ea270643a774ad07ddedfee79cc57966)*

Comment: Is there any equivalence in SQL-Server?

Comment: @ToniCuc Updated

Comment: I think I have been obfuscated trying to create a field that would be the combination of the incremental and the ARTICODI when perhaps the easiest solution is to use the incremental and ARTICODI as constraint pk

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed column for that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CENTRALCOMPRASSTG..ProveedoresCatalogo(
  InternalIdentityID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  IDProveedoresCatalogo = CAST(CONCAT(InternalIdentityID, ARTICODI) AS INT),
  PRVECODI NUMERIC(9,0),
  GRUPDESC NVARCHAR(40),
  FAMIDESC NVARCHAR(40),
  ARTICODI NUMERIC(9,0),
  PROVREFER NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNMARCA NVARCHAR(20),
  PPLNORIGEN NVARCHAR(50),
  ACUERDOS INT,
  SBFMDESC NVARCHAR(40)
)
```

or (maybe this one is faster):

```
CREATE TABLE CENTRALCOMPRASSTG..ProveedoresCatalogo(
  InternalIdentityID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  IDProveedoresCatalogo = InternalIdentityID * POWER(10, LEN(ARTICODI)) + ARTICODI,
(...)
```

Comment: Is there any equivalence in SQL-Server?

Comment: This might create issues if you are doing `CONCAT( 1, 7102 )` and `CONCAT( 17, 102 )`.

Comment: @MT0 it surely might. But that is basically the requirement ![https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ue1.png]